# Laplacian with Integral BC(s)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, problem-solving, heat-equation, laplacian, elliptic-equations

I want to solve the three-dimensional laplacian 
$$\nabla^{2} T = 0$$ where $\nabla^2 = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}$
defined on $x\in[0,L],y\in[0,l],z\in[-w,0]$ with the following boundary conditions

$$\frac{\partial T(0,y,z)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial T(L,y,z)}{\partial x}=0 \rightarrow Neumann$$

$$\frac{\partial T(x,0,z)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial T(x,l,z)}{\partial y}=0\rightarrow Neumann$$

$$\frac{\partial T(x,y,-w)}{\partial z}=p_h\bigg( T(x,y,-w) -  \frac{e^\frac{-b_h x}{L}b_h}{L}\int e^\frac{b_h x}{L}T\mathrm{d}x \bigg) \rightarrow Convection$$

$$\frac{\partial T(x,y,0)}{\partial z}=p_c\bigg(\frac{e^\frac{-b_c y}{l}b_c}{l}\int e^\frac{b_c y}{l}T\mathrm{d}y -T(x,y,0) \bigg)\rightarrow Convection$$
$b_h,b_c,p_h,p_c,L,l$ are constants $>0$

**Addendum** The physical situation that this problem describes has two additional pieces of information
$\rightarrow$ At $(0,y,-w)$ $\rightarrow$ $\frac{e^\frac{-b_h x}{L}b_h}{L}\int e^\frac{b_h x}{L}T\mathrm{d}x = T_{h,i}$ *a constant*

and

At $(x,0,0)$ $\rightarrow$ $\frac{e^\frac{-b_c y}{l}b_c}{l}\int e^\frac{b_c y}{l}T\mathrm{d}y = T_{c,i}$ *a constant*

**Attempt**

I know that for the 3D Laplacian,, when separation of variables is applied the following holds

$k_x^{2} + k_y^{2} = k_z^{2}$

So if $X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$ is substituted as $T$ we can say $X \sim \cos(n\pi x)$, $Y \sim \cos(m \pi y)$. I know that Z can be  some hyperbolic function like $[A_{m,n}\cosh(\pi \sqrt{n^2 + m^2}) + B_{m,n}\cosh(\pi \sqrt{n^2 + m^2})]$

But when the solution form is substituted onto the $z$ bc, what i get is just two homogeneous linear equations in $A_{m,n}$ and $B_{m,n}$. From this point, I cannot proceed.

Any help or guidance on how this problem can be tackled will be appreciated.

***Attempt 2***

As suggested by @DisintegratingByParts I need to divide the problem into two parts.

Let us take Problem 1.

As already mentioned,I have the additional info that:

At $(0,y,-w)$ $\rightarrow$ $\frac{e^\frac{-b_h x}{L}b_h}{L}\int e^\frac{b_h x}{L}T\mathrm{d}x = T_{h,i}$.

So we can write

$$\frac{\partial T(x,y,-w)}{\partial z}=p_h\bigg( T(x,y,-w) -  \frac{e^\frac{-b_h x}{L}b_h}{L}\int e^\frac{b_h x}{L}T\mathrm{d}x \bigg)  $$

as

$$\frac{\partial T(0,y,-w)}{\partial z}=p_h\bigg( T(0,y,-w) -  T_{h,i} \bigg)$$

So now i have the boundary condition (more like an edge condition in 3D) without the integral on the RHS. 
Can this BC be used along with the others to form a solution of *Problem 1* or am i wrong in some way ?

---

On applying the third BC from Problem 1 but at $(x,y,-w)$ I arrive at

$$
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n,m}\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\cos(\frac{m\pi y}{l})\sqrt{\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2}+\frac{m^2\pi^2}{l^2}}\sinh\bigg(w\sqrt{\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2}+\frac{m^2\pi^2}{l^2}}\bigg) = p_h\bigg(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n,m}\cos(\frac{m\pi y}{l})\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\cosh\bigg(w\sqrt{\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2}+\frac{m^2\pi^2}{l^2}}\bigg) - \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{A_{n,m}b_h}{b_h^2 + n^2 \pi^2 }\cos(\frac{m\pi y}{l})\cosh\bigg(w\sqrt{\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2}+\frac{m^2\pi^2}{l^2}}\bigg)\bigg[b_h\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) + n\pi\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L}) \bigg]\bigg)
$$

This needs to be now solved for Fourier coefficients $A_{n,m}$. I know that we have to somehow use the property of orthogonality of the Eigen functions, but the problem pertains from the fact that $A_{n,m}$ exist on both sides of the equation.

Comment: What do you mean by $\nabla^3$?

Comment: $\Delta$ or $\nabla^2$ stands for the Laplacian in any dimension. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator .

Comment: You have asked essentially the same question three times now, in this post, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3105909/3d-homogenous-laplace-equation-with-integral-boundary-conditions) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3108545/3d-heat-equation-with-integral-boundary-conditions-contextual-information-added). It is ridiculous to keep posting the same question but adding new context or details to the problem.

Comment: @Mattos I can understand that. The first time I asked it , I included an attempt after recommendation from comments and the question itself became too long, so I reposted a new question with more bqckground information. I am sorry if i have broken the community rules by doing this.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts I have made the edit as suggested by you. Can you provide some inputs here ?

Comment: @VasilyMitch Using $\nabla^3$ was a mistake, I wanted to express the Laplacian in 3D. I have edited the question to reflect the changes.

Comment: @Mattos Could you provide some guiding points on the problem here ?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve two problems and sum the two solutions:

**Problem 1**
$$\frac{\partial T(0,y,z)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial T(L,y,z)}{\partial x}=0 \rightarrow Neumann$$

$$\frac{\partial T(x,0,z)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial T(x,l,z)}{\partial y}=0\rightarrow Neumann$$

$$\frac{\partial T(x,y,-w)}{\partial z}=p_h\bigg( T(x,y,-w) -  \frac{e^\frac{-b_h x}{L}b_h}{L}\int e^\frac{b_h x}{L}T\mathrm{d}x \bigg) \rightarrow Convection$$

$$
\frac{\partial T(x,y,0)}{\partial z} = 0.
$$

**Problem 2**
$$\frac{\partial T(0,y,z)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial T(L,y,z)}{\partial x}=0 \rightarrow Neumann$$

$$\frac{\partial T(x,0,z)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial T(x,l,z)}{\partial y}=0\rightarrow Neumann$$

$$
   \frac{\partial T(x,y,-w)}{\partial z} = 0.
$$

$$\frac{\partial T(x,y,0)}{\partial z}=p_c\bigg(\frac{e^\frac{-b_c y}{l}b_c}{l}\int e^\frac{b_c y}{l}T\mathrm{d}y -T(x,y,0) \bigg)\rightarrow Convection$$

The **Problem 1** Form of solution is
$$
        T(x,y,z)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n,m}\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\cos(\frac{m\pi y}{l})\cosh\left(\sqrt{\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2}+\frac{m^2\pi^2}{l^2}}z\right).
$$
The constants $A_{n,m}$ are determined as Fourier coefficients through the third condition at $z=-w$.

Comment: Thanks. Now i get that since its a linear operator , the total solution can be a superposition. I have added an *Attempt2* to my original problem which makes the BC free from the integral. If possible have a look. I have some reservations about it.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra : I added more to help you put the final pieces into place.

Comment: This was great. I will try this now. Actually, my dilemma was whether I should use the modified condition at $x=0,y,z=-w$ (which forms an edge of the whole 3D domain, not a face)or the condition at $x,y,z=-w$ (which forms a face). Is there some restrictions like the bc(s) for  a 3D domain should be only planes ?

Comment: @IndrasisMitra : If you're going to use separation of variables to solve your problem, then the boundaries must be surfaces that are defined by setting one of the variables to a constant. In Cartesian coordinates, such surfaces are planes. If my answer is sufficient, please press the check mark next to it to accept the answer. You can also +1 it if you are so inclined.

Comment: +1'd it already. Also, I applied the b.c. at $(x,y,-w)$  viz. a surface (have added it to the end of the question). The difficulty i now face is that the constant $A_{n,m}$  appear on both sides of the resulting equation. Any hint you can provide to find these coeff.(s) ? You have been a great help anyway

Comment: I have been trying to find the Fourier coefficients with the suggested solution form using orthogonality of the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions but the final step where i try to determine $A_{n,m}$, the coefficients just cancel out from both sides. Is this solution form supposed to work for such Robin type conditions ? Finally, it would be very helpful if you could look again at the $Problem1$ sub-part and give it a try ?